# Ocaml loop tail recursion

Tags: list, ocaml, tail-recursion

I have basically completed my homework, as I only needed a certain amount of working test examples. My only issue is I cannot figure out why this does not work, and I would like to know for my sanity.

```
let list_helper (x: 'a -> bool) head = if (x head) then true else false
let take_while (x: 'a -> bool) lst = 
    let rec take_while_helper x lst acc = match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> if list_helper x h then take_while_helper x t (h::acc) else acc in take_while_helper x lst []
```

- `take_while (fun _ -> true) [1; 2; 3]` should evaluate to `[1; 2; 3]`. This one does not work.
- `take_while ((=) "a") ["a"; "a"; "b"; "a"]` should evaluate to `["a"; "a"]`. Works as expected.
- `take_while (fun _ -> false) ["say"; "anything"]` should evaluate to `[]`. Works as expected.

The last two test cases work, but the first one does not. I made another similar function, and again it does not work. It seems my function does not handle integers well, and I do not know why. I would like to know why it is not behaving correctly, as I though through it logically and it seems like it should work. Maybe I'm missing something about integers and lists.

Comment: What output do you get instead? Why might that be?

Comment: Btw, `list_helper x h` is equivalent to `x h`. `if … then true else false` is the identity function on booleans - just drop it.

Comment: Besides not working with the first test case, I think it also doesn't work with `take_while (fun x -> x < "c") ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"]`

Comment: True, forgot to return the accumulator as stated by Harald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to return the accumulator in the case of an empty list. And you have to reverse the result, since you add the elements to the accumulator in the wrong order.

So your function could look like

```
let take_while (x: 'a -> bool) lst = 
  let rec take_while_helper lst acc = match lst with
  | [] -> acc
  | h::t -> if x h then (take_while_helper t (h::acc)) else acc
  in List.rev (take_while_helper lst [])
```

Comment: Ah, I see I forgot to return the accumulator, thanks, I now see why it's wrong.